# Can't convert String into integer while parsing google maps api

Tags: ruby, string, google-maps

I am trying to fetch the latitude and longitude of a particular location following http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/methods-and-gems/

```
Here is the snippet:
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest-client'
require 'crack'

def get_coordinates_from_address(addr)
   base_google_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address="
   res = RestClient.get(URI.encode("#{base_google_url}#{addr}"))
   parsed_res = Crack::XML.parse(res)
   lat = parsed_res["GeocodeResponse"]["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
   lng = parsed_res["GeocodeResponse"]["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]

   return "#{lat}, #{lng}"
end      

latlng = get_coordinates_from_address("1 Times Square, NYC")
puts latlng
```

I am getting the following stack trace:

```
/Users/archie/agile/latlang.rb:9:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from /Users/archie/agile/latlang.rb:9:in `get_coordinates_from_address'
    from /Users/archie/agile/latlang.rb:15:in `<main>'
[Finished]
```

What is the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know. [The XML](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1%20Times%20Square,%20NYC&sensor=false) has several `result`s, so `parsed_res["GeocodeResponse"]["result"]` is really an array. I don't really know Ruby or crack, but my hunch is you need to address an index to result (usually the first result is best, so use 0), and write something like

```
parsed_res["GeocodeResponse"]["result"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
```

or maybe

```
firstResult = parsed_res["GeocodeResponse"]["result"][0]
lat = firstResult["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
```

<sup>my notation is probably wrong, sorry!</sup>

Comment: It may also be worth commenting that those values are not integers, and converting the Strings into Integers may not give the results intended.